# Construct for accepting STDIN and parameter argument in Perl

Tags: perl, stdin, argv

I want my perl script to be able to do this:

```
$ ./code file.txt | myperl.pl param1 param2
```

So basically it will take input (STIDN) from `./code` and execute it with `param1` and `param2`.

But why this doesn't work:

```
my $param1 = $ARGV[0];
my $param2 = $ARGV[1];

while (<>) {
   if ($param1 > 0.5 && $param2 > 0) {
     # do something
  }

}
```

What's the right construct to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<>` aka `readline`'s default argument is ARGV, which is a magic filehandle that reads from all the files specified in @ARGV, or from STDIN if there are none.  Since you are providing arguments, you either need to clear them out of @ARGV before using `<>`, or explicitly specify `<STDIN>` and not use the magic ARGV handle.

Answer (score 5):

This works, it removes the first two params for @ARGV:

```
my $param1 = shift;
my $param2 = shift;

while (<>) {
   if ($param1 > 0.5 && $param2 > 0) {
     # do something
   }
}
```

`<>` (short for `<ARGV>`) reads from from the files listed in `@ARGV` if `@ARGV` isn't empty. When it's empty (such as in the above because you shifted the options out), it reads from `STDIN` instead.

The alternative would be to use `<STDIN>` instead of `<>`, but then the caller loses the option of doing `myperl.pl param1 param2 file.txt`.

Comment: I prefer this approach, so I added an explanation to complete the answer.

Comment: with ikegami's addition, this answer is better and should be accepted

Answer (score 4):

You must use `<STDIN>` in this case.

```
my $param1 = $ARGV[0];
my $param2 = $ARGV[1];

while (<STDIN>) {
   if ($param1 > 0.5 && $param2 > 0) {
     # do something
  }

}
```

The *diamond*-operator `<>` means arguments + stdin.

When you want use the diamond operator instead of `<STDIN>`, you must remove these two arguments `param1` and `param2` from `ARGV` before. But I think that `<STDIN>` would be in your case better.

Comment: Actually, `<>` means arguments || STDIN. ) But it still can be used, if one of the arguments is '-'.

Comment: @raina77ow: yes, you are right, it would be better to write `arguments` || `stdin`